# html form.input.value is not getting printed why?

Tags: javascript, html

...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function printvalues() {
  document.write("This is my first JavaScript!");
  document.write(form.inputobj1.value);
  document.write(form.inputobj2.value);
 }
</script>
<form name="form">
 <input name="inputobj1" value="123" />
 <input name="inputobj2" value="abc"/>
 <input type="button" onclick =" printvalues();"> 
</form>
```

why this line is not printing the value `document.write(form.inputobj1.value);`

Comment: What *does* it do? What's the full HTML & Javascript code? Do any errors appear in the error console?

Comment: just i am learning html. i have posted html but it is not displaying in stackoverflow. 
this gives inputobj1 is not an object

Comment: i call the printvalues() from a form that has two input objects named 
inputobj1 and inputobj2. while clicking a button from the form am calling the function

Answer (score 3):

The `document.write` overwrites the current document. Once done that, the whole `<form>` element disappears from the DOM and hence it and its input elements cannot be found.

Replace `document.write(...)` by for example `alert(...)` and it should work.

Alternatively you can write it as `innerHTML` of another element. E.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printvalues() {
        var div = document.getElementById("divId");
        div.innerHTML += "This is my first JavaScript!";
        div.innerHTML += form.inputobj1.value;
        div.innerHTML += form.inputobj2.value;
    }
</script>
<form name="form">
    <input name="inputobj1" value="123" />
    <input name="inputobj2" value="abc"/>
    <input type="button" onclick =" printvalues();"> 
</form>
<div id="divId"></div>
```

Note that this is not the "best practice", but since you're learning... When done with core Javascript, I recommend you to get yourself through [jQuery](http://jquery.com). It's a Javascript library which greatly eases DOM manipulation like that and more ;)

Comment: You're welcome. I see that you're new at Stackoverflow. If an answer is *helpful*, you are free to upvote it. If an answer *did* solve your question/problem, you are supposed to mark it as accepted. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

```
document.write()
```

is probably not what you want.  It will overwrite the entire contents of the page.  The reason you're getting that error is because when you call document.write, it removes all the previous content, and thus the page will no longer have a form element.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use a function such as `document.getElementById` to get a DOM element. For example:

```
alert( document.getElementById('inputobj1_id').value );
```

For DOM element:

```
<input id="inputobj1_id" name="inputobj1" value="123" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printvalues() {
var x = document.form.inputobj1.value;
var y = document.form.inputobj2.value
document.write("<Html><head></head><body><h1>");
document.write("This is my first JavaScript!</h1></br><h3>");
document.write(x);document.write("</h3></br><h3>");
document.write(y);document.write("</h3></body></html>");
}
</script>
<form name="form">
<input name="inputobj1" value="123" />
<input name="inputobj2" value="abc"/>
<input type="button" value="click" onclick =" printvalues();"> 
</form>
```